# Epimorphism from free product to direct product of groups.

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism, free-groups

Let $G_1$ and $G_2$ be two non abelian groups and $G_1 * G_2$ be the free product of these two groups. Can we define an epimorphism from $G_1 *G_2$ to the direct product $G_1 \times   G_2$ of these groups.

I think for abelian groups it is easy to do, but for non how can we do this. Please help me regarding this.

Comment: Why are assuming that $G_1$ and $G_2$ are non-abelian? That seems irrelevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition of free product, whenever you have homomorphisms $f_i\colon G_i\to X$, then there is a unique homomorphism $G_1*G_2\to X$ that looks like $f_i$ on $G_i\subset G_1*G_2$. For $X=G_1\times G_2$, we can simple use the canonical inclusions $G_i\to G_1\times G_2$ as our $f_i$. Long story short, with $g_{i,j}\in G_i$, this maps $g_{1,1}g_{2,1}g_{1,2}g_{2,2}g_{1,3}\cdots g_{2,n}\mapsto \langle g_{1,1}g_{1,2}\cdots, g_{1,n}\,g_{2,1}g_{2,2}\cdots, g_{2,n}\rangle$.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**. *(hint)* the [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(algebra)#Group_homomorphisms) of $\phi : G * H \rightarrow G \times H$ should be equal to subgroup of $ G * H$ generated by $\{g^{-1}h^{-1}gh \in G * H \ | \ g \in G \land h \in H\} = \{x\in G * H \ | \ \phi(x) = 0 \}$.

Comment: I *think* your first set should be "subgroup generated by". In general, you don't even know if the product of two of these commutators is itself a commutator. E.g., if $G=\mathbb{Z}^2$ and $H=\mathbb{Z}$, then $[(1,0),1][(0,1),1]$ is not of the given form.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean the second set $G \times H$? The free product is *uniquely* defined *up to* isomorphism. $G * H$ is defined as words over the alphabet $G \cup H$ with all of the relations inherited from $G$ and $H$. If $G = \mathbb{Z}^2$ and $H = \mathbb{Z}$ then it is not entirely clear what $[(0,1),1][(0,1),1]$ is. For example, a typical element of $G * H$ will look like $(g_1,g_2)h_1(g_3,g_4) ... (g_{2n-1},g_{2n})h_n$ where $g_i ,h_i \in \mathbb{Z}$. Could you please elaborate, I am having trouble understanding your statement? From your notation it seems you mean the second set

Comment: Nevermind, I think you meant the kernel, not $G$ or $H$. Yea sure, simple typo, I'll fix it thanks. The kernel should be the "group generated $\{g^{−1}h^{−1}gh \in G* H | g \in G \land h \in H\}$." Is that what you were trying to say? No need for such an in-depth (mildly patronizing) description for such a triviality. But I nonetheless appreciate your taking the time to help. You know there is an edit feature. Why don't you edit it to your liking next time and I will approve the edit. It saves us a lot more time, don't you think? Now is the perfect opportunity to try it out ... go ahead.

Comment: Yes, that’s what I meant; and I’m sorry it came across patronizing: in fact, a lot of people have trouble with the commutator subgroup/cartesian thinking it is the set of commutators, and that not every product of commutators is a commutator. As for [try]ing it out... I don’t like correcting what could be errors without allowing the authors to do it themselves. That practice has served me well for the time I’ve been here.

Comment: No worries. Glad it’s been cleared up.